# Is there some HTML annotation tool for adding annotations to downloaded HTML files?

Tags: linux, html, html-editor, annotation

I would like to add annotations (such as underlines, text comment, circle or square a text region, …) to downloaded HTML files.

Is there some WYSIWYG HTML annotation tool (for Linux; I am under Ubuntu) for that purpose?

Comment: Adding a comment or taking a screenshot and annotating doesn't cut it?